# Weird output format for date input type

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I'm making a web app with Laravel and I want to filter elements by creation date. The format I need is `yyyy-mm-dd`.
This is what I've tried:

Form to pick a date:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('dateFilter',[$subject,$date]) }}">
    <input type="date" class="datepicker" name="date" >
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $subject }}" name="subject">

    <input class="btn btn-primary submit-date" type="submit" name="submitDate">
</form>
```

This is the route I created:

```php
Route::get('/view/{subject}/{date}', 'EntryController@filter')->name('dateFilter');
```

And this is the function on the controller, it just displays the output for now just to get this step done:

```php
public function filter($request){
    print_r($request);
}
```

Right now if I try to pick a date and submit the form I get the following url:
`http://localhost/view/LMSG/Tuesday,%2008/10%20?date=2019-10-07&subject=LMSG`

What I need to have is something like `/view/LMSG/2019-10-07`

Comment: tell your datepicker (configure) to return the date in the format you want it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('dateFilter',[$subject, $date->format('Y-m-d')]) }}">
```